# Need help with monitor install

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a Lenovo ThinkCcentre I have installed Ubuntu on so I can start getting good with Linux again. I have installed an additional DVI port in the tower to run multiple monitors and used a DVI to dual VGA cable. When I installed the new DVI video card my old VGA port stopped working. I currently have two monitors running off the new DVI to dual VGA but would really like to get my old VGA port running again to have the third monitor for work reasons. When running `xrander` it is not even reading the old VGA port. I do have a monitor connected but will not get a signal at all. Here is the output:

`xrandr -q`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3600 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DIN disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-1 connected 1680x1050+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 433mm x 271mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+  74.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08
```

Does anyone have any ideas or the conf pages I can edit?

Comment: Just to add- When i installed the DVI card my existing VGA port stopped working completely. Even when i go to setting/display it does not register.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* this is a older machine (2011 or before for intel, not sure for AMD) , the PCI lanes used for the video card were often also used for integrated graphics. After this, the iGPU was put on the same die for most lower end machines, so this would not be an issue.

Even if you had "on die" graphics, the BIOS settings you need to change might not be visible - this would be called something like "[iGPU Multi-Monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/523928/how-do-i-run-the-integrated-video-adaptor-alongside-the-gpu-on-a-ivy-bridge-syst/523929#523929)"

My guess is that your on board video is getting disabled when you install your discrete card. Ubuntu isn't at fault - chances are its the hardware behaving as its designed to "protect" the user (windows didn't like dissimilar video cards being installed till... I think windows 7) and to save on PCIe lanes.

Comment: Yes this is definitely an older machine but it does have intel. Thank you for the response. So i take it i will be stuck with the DVI splitter ? I can check the BIOS  for the iGPU multi-monitor settings and i figured it was something to do with this Lenova. I mainly wanted to get my son learning Linux but if this doesnt work i can just use the duel monitors.